# Is the structure/construction of the sentence wrong? What can I tweak to correct the sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

This does not sound right.

> As the war progressed, the federal government came under immense pressure to establish a national system of labour offices, prompted by *concerns over the shortage of manpower for the warfare* **and**, more importantly, *the threat of the post-war social upheaval*.

I am trying to convey this:

> As the war progressed, the federal government came under immense pressure to establish a national system of labour offices. Such was prompted by:
>
> 1. concerns over the shortage of manpower for the warfare.
> 2. the threat of the post-war social upheaval (this was more important in creating the pressure).

I feel that "more importantly" is essential to the meaning and so I am not sure if I should set if of with a pair of commas starting right after "and". Apart from that, when I read the sentence and get to "...prompted by...", I forget everything that came before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence sounds perfect to me.

If you're concerned about the length, it's appropriate for the subject matter. It's a complex but single thought. Breaking it into pieces, multiple sentences, would be awkward and confusing.

Your commas are in the correct places. The rule is that a comma represents a brief pause, e.g., for emphasis or an aside, when speaking.